# Актер/артист

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажи, пожалуйста, правильно ли говорить: "нравится артист в этом фильме"? Или допустим только вариант "нравится актер в этом фильме"?

Answer (score 2):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

АРТИСТ, [франц. artiste].1.Об актёре, певце, музыканте и т.п. А. эстрады, театра, кино. Оперный, цирковой а.
2. Разг. О том, кто достиг высокого мастерства, совершенства в чём-л. А. своего дела, в своём деле.

АКТЁР, [франц. acteur].
1.Профессиональный исполнитель ролей в театральных представлениях или в кинофильмах. Мастерство актёра. Трагедийный, комический а.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Лучше сказать так: "Мне нравится актер (исполнитель определенной роли) в этом фильме.  Он выдающийся артист". Как правило, актер - это просто действующее лицо, а артист - это высокая оценка мастерства.

Comment: Но сказать "нравится артист в этом фильме" правильно?

Comment: Вообще часто можно услышать: мне нравится этот артист, мне он нравится и как артист, и как режиссер, то есть называется профессия.  Можно сказать" мне нравится артист N в этом фильме". Но лучше сказать: "Мне нравится актер, который исполняет эту роль". Хотя и "артист" тоже можно сказать. Возможно, здесь немного разные оттенки значений: (1)мне нравится эта работа (об актере) и (2) мне нравится этот артист как мастер своей профессии.

Answer (score 1):

На слуху "актер театра" и никогда "артист театра". А когда речь идет о концерте, говорят "выступает артист". Опять же Народный или Заслуженный только артист. Я бы сказала  "нравится артист в этом фильме".

Comment: Возможно, слова актер/артист желательно употреблять в разных ситуациях с учетом различных смысловых оттенков: (1)Мне нравится артист N в этом фильме. (Это значит: мне нравится, как артист N сыграл эту конкретную роль). (2)Мне нравится актер, исполняющий главную роль в этом фильме. Это известный артист N.

Comment: Может быть. Надо прислушаться к высказываниям на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Актёр - одно  значений  слова  артист.  В  производных  этой  пары  это  заметней,  там  значение  может  разойтись  сильнее,  например:  актёрское  мастерство (  узкое  значение )  и  артистизм  (широкое  значение,  относится  не только к  актёрам,  но  к  другим  деятелям  искусства). Или  при  оценке  мастерства  какого-либо  специалиста,  указывает  на  его высшую  степень.

Comment: А вы как скажете: " Мне нравится артист/актер в этом фильме"? Это равноправное употребление слов, или они различаются по смыслу/стилю?

Comment: Мне  кажется,  что  точнее  было  бы  сказать  актёр,  но  для  этой  фразы  оба  слова  подойдут.  У  аудитории  вопросов  не  возникнет.

Comment: А вот  была такая серия книг "Актеры советского кино", "Артисты советского кино" не звучит. Получается, что нет сочетаемости "артист кино", неполная сочетаемость "артист в фильме"? А если нет прямой привязки "артист кино", то в одном предложении они могут встречаться.

Comment: Конечно,  "артисты  советского  кино" не  звучит,  а  "артист  кино"  уже  лучше,  а  "киноартист"  вполне  звучит.  По  моему  в  словосочетании  "артист  кино"  сочетаемость  всё  же  есть. А  ваше  последнее  предложение  утвердительное  или  вопросительное ?  Или  там  "не"  пропущено ?

Comment: Скорее, вопросительное. Или наблюдательное. Я хотела сказать, что здесь, может быть,  действует общее правило употребления слов в неполной сочетаемостью: чем они дальше друг от друга, тем корректнее выглядят.

Comment: В Нацкорпусе: артист кино - 2, актер кино - 5, киноартист - 3 страницы.